# Excel VBA - Reinitialize a Range

Tags: vba, excel

In a macro, I am applying the same treatment in each Worksheets of the file.

I want to determine which column contains a specific text, which might be different in each Worksheet.

The code is as follows:

```
For Each Cell_version In Ws.Range("1:1")
    If Ws.Range(convertir(Cell_version.Column) & "1") = "ICI" Then
        Column_version = convertir(Cell_version.Column)
        Trouve_col = True
        MsgBox (Column_version)
    End If
If Trouve_col = True Then Exit For
Next Cell_version
```

On the first Worksheet, everything functions appropriately, and finds the text in the appropriate column `column D`. In the second Worksheet, if the column is after column D, it function as well. However, if it is `column A, B, or C`, it does not return the column containing the desired text. How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My VBA is a bit rusty, but I always preferred the `Find` command, since it is the fastest way to search a worksheet, like this perhaps:

```
Sheets("YourSheet").Select

Cells(1, 1).Select

Set found = Cells.Find(What:="ICI", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlColumn, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not found Is Nothing Then
    found.Activate      
    MsgBox(Selection.Row)
End If
```